# date UTC in datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

Having problem showing small date. Currently it shows long UTC date with time.

```
var events = [ 
    { Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("03/13/2013"), Time: "11:15" }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("03/25/2013"), Time: "11:15" }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2013"), Time: "11:15" }
];


        for(var d=0;d<events.length;d++) {
        $('.myarray').append('<div><span>'+events[d].Title + '</span><br>' + events[d].Date + '<br>' + events[d].Time + '<br><br></div>');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `event[]` array should be like this:

```
var events = [{
   Title: "Five K for charity",
   Date: "03/13/2013",
   Time: "11:15"
}, {
   Title: "Dinner",
   Date: "03/25/2013",
   Time: "11:15"
}, {
   Title: "Meeting with manager",
   Date: "03/01/2013",
   Time: "11:15"
}];
```

`Date: new Date("03/25/2013"),` This creates a full date and time with standards.